# Messenger API : bypass messenger browser

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-messenger, messenger

I'm building a webapp where users chan share links to other users.

**Lets illustrate my problem with an example:**

- Alice is using the webapp.
- Alice shares a link to Bob through messenger API.
- Bob clicks the link that opens in the messenger browser.
- Bob wants to share a link to Chris **but it's not working since
  messenger API can't open itself inside messenger browser !**

I tried to fix this by adding `href="_blank"` but links keep opening theirselves inside the messenger browser.

Is there way to bypass messenger browser when user click on links (and use users' default browser instead) ? Without using Facebook settings.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no such thing in the [Messenger Platform Reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference). Only the user can choose to bypass Messenger's browser in favor of his default mobile browser, through Messenger's settings.

`href="_blank"` shouldn't have any effect for two reasons:

1. It is written incorrectly. The correct syntax is `target="_blank"`
2. Even if it was written correctly, because it actually only tells the browser to open something in a new tab (or Window) not a different browser. Messenger's browser just ignores it since it doesn't support tabs.